# How to connect to metamask with react 2020

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, metamask

I saw how to connect to metamask with react in 2020 because alot of how to connect to metamask is deprecated. Docs say the currennt updated way to connect to metamask is the module @web3-react/injected-connector and then to use this

```
const injected = new InjectedConnector({
  // Chain IDs for metamask network
  supportedChainIds: [1598738245329, 1337, 5777, 1, 3, 4, 5, 10, 42, 77, 99, 100]
});
```

my question is how do i use the constant above to open the metamask extension to choose a wallet to connect to the dapp? also I am not using a functional component i am using a class. I am still learning react and have not fully understand the way to translate react hooks into a class like useWeb3React for instance or do i HAVE to use a functional component to be able to open metamask and get account information? Also in the examples of the docs it shows it in tsx, I was hoping someone here could show me how to do it in jsx!

Comment: Your best bet is using `window.ethereum.enable` In this tutorial on creating a NFT minter with React, they have a completed example on how to use it: https://docs.alchemyapi.io/alchemy/tutorials/nft-minter#step-4-connect-metamask-to-your-ui